# iOS — Are UITableViewCell reuseIdentifiers global?

Tags: iphone, ios

What is the scope of the table view cell's reuse identifiers — are they shared within one table view instance or within all the table views that use the same reuse identifier?

Eg, I have a FooTableViewController and a BarTableViewController, both of them have a tableView and both of them use @"Cell" identifier in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath, but the cell properties/styling are different. The question is - will those cells be reused across table views or not?

Comment: they are not reused across tableViews ., they are reused only within that tableView

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are never shared between instances.

> A UITableView object maintains a queue (or list) of the currently reusable cells, each with its own reuse identifier, and makes them available to the delegate in the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method.

(from `[UITableViewCell reuseIdentifier]` docs)

Emphasis on "UITableView object".

However, you should make your cell identifiers more descriptive. A different identifier for every cell type you are using. Your code will be more readable.

Answer (score 6):

They will only be used in a single `UITableView`, they will never be shared. Each `UITableView` has its own "pool" of reusable `UITableViewCells`